# why is my while loop not breaking in this simple calculator? What mistake did I make?

Tags: python-3.x

My loop is not breaking, what can I do? What is the mistake that I made? Please help

```
  while True:
    choice = int(input("Enter (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"))
    num_1 = float(input("Enter number 1 "))
    num_2 = float(input("Enter number 2"))
    if choice == 1:
        print(num_1, "+ ", num_2, "= ", add(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 2:
        print(num_1, "- ", num_2, "= ", subtract(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 3:
        print(num_1, "+ ", num_2,  "= ", multiply(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice ==4:
        print(num_1, "+", num_2, "=", divide(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 5:
        break
```

Comment: You need to test if `choice == 5` immediately after it is read else it will ask for the 2 numbers _then_ break.

Answer (score 0):

```
alpha =True
while alpha:
    choice = int(input("Enter (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"))
    if choice ==5:
      break
    num_1 = float(input("Enter number 1 "))
    num_2 = float(input("Enter number 2"))
    if choice == 1:
        print(num_1, "+ ", num_2, "= ", num_1+num_2)
    elif choice == 2:
        print(num_1, "- ", num_2, "= ", num_1-num_2)
    elif choice == 3:
        print(num_1, "* ", num_2,  "= ", num_1*num_2)
    elif choice ==4:
        print(num_1, "/", num_2, "=", num_1/num_2)
```

Actually your code is performing correctly but it is first taking input of the choice, then it is taking input of two numbers and then it is comparing with the if else statements.

When your choice is 5 , it first takes inputs of two numbers and then it checks that choice ==5 and breaks the loop.

I have changed the position of if else statement so it can work in a better way.